# Not reporting very small income on my U.S. account while I live abroad

Tags: income-tax, irs, non-resident, tax-exemption

I grew up and lived in the U.S. until graduating from university. After graduation I took a job abroad where I have been living now for 5 years.

Since beginning my job, I have been filing a U.S. tax return and paying some U.S. tax (which is awful because I don't live in the U.S., earn much money in the U.S. or get any services from the U.S. but alas that is the law. It also means I can't save money or invest like my neighbours and friends can. It's absolute tyranny, but I digress)

However I do earn **some** money in the U.S. - about $3000 per year. This money comes from some friends and family who I do small artistic jobs for. It is much easier for them to send money to my U.S. bank account than to send money overseas, and I use this money when I visit the U.S. once or twice a year.

I am wondering how risky this is for me vis-a-vis the IRS.

On one hand, I might be evading taxes (however little), but on the other if I were to report it, the process is so complicated and time-consuming that I would most likely not do these small jobs anyway. Do I need to worry about this or can I can carry on with these small jobs worry-free?

Comment: "It also means I can't save money or invest" Why not?

Comment: @RupertMorrish because I have to pay taxes to both the US and my adopted country. Yes some types of retirement accounts are exempt from most - but not all - double taxing, but regular savings are not. Also I cannot take advantage of local benefits like no capital gains tax on sale of primary residence, so I'm at a major disadvantage in the local market, where everything is priced based on this benefit. Basically while the U.S. might be the land of freedom for those inside her borders, once you leave her borders it is hell.

Comment: @RupertMorrish another crucial point is that I am not able to effectively save for my children's education. Foreign tax-advantaged education funds are not exempt from U.S. taxes so there is essentially no point in having one. And I can't open a U.S. one since I am not a resident there

Comment: On the other hand, you'll have a chance to get your children educated outside the USA for so much less that you won't have to save for it.

Comment: Good point on the capital gains tax.

Comment: "I cannot take advantage of local benefits like no capital gains tax on sale of primary residence" US$250,000 CGT exemption if you've lived in it for 2 of the past 5 years, according to our accountant.

Comment: @RupertMorrish thanks that is good to know, regarding the capital gains tax on residence.

Comment: Regarding your comment `"you'll have a chance to get your children educated outside the USA for so much less that you won't have to save for it."` that's silly. By the time my kids are in college I will have paid for it through my taxes for a couple of decades. It's not actually that much cheaper. So I'll be paying local taxes AND paying tax to the U.S. government for my kids educations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your gross income is only $3000, then you don't need to file:

https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p501.pdf

That said, pay careful attention to:

https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/taxpayers-living-abroad

You should be reporting ALL income, without regard to WHERE you earned it, on your US taxes. Not doing so could indeed get you in trouble if you are audited. Your level of worry depends on how much of the tax law you are willing to dodge, and how lucky you feel.

Comment: That's what I'm not sure about... I earn around $40K abroad, but only $3K in the U.S. Thus my total earnings are more than $4050, but not in the U.S.

Comment: @CH - it's my understanding that the total income is what counts and all of it must be reported. Your worldwide income is subject to U.S. income tax, regardless of where you reside.

Comment: Your overseas income is below the foreign earned income exclusion (about $85k) so you shouldn't have to pay tax on it, so long as you are working for a company. 
But you need to declare it. Go see an accountant and get them to help you file amendments to your past few years filings.

Comment: Oh, and you need to file a report for every foreign bank account you have that's had over US$10k in it at any time in the year.

Comment: @Robert Moorish:  The threshold for FBAR reporting is a *total* of $10,000 in all foreign accounts...